# Why is $x-(x-1)=1$ instead of $x-x-1=-1$ as in $a*(b*c)=a*b*c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, field-theory, arithmetic

As in the title of the question, why is $x-(x-1)=1$ instead of $x-x-1=-1$ as in $a*(b*c)=a*b*c$? Is there any intuitive example to explain it?

Comment: An example might help. $100-(100-1)=100-(99)=1$, but $100-100-1=0-1=-1$.

Comment: In most cases, a question of the form “Why isn’t ...” will be beside the point. Rather, you should be asking “Why is ...”. For multiplication, you can answer the question “why is $a(bc)=(ab)c)$?” in a provisional way by noticing that it seems always to be true when you try numbers for $a$, $b$, and $c$. And you answer it in a definitive way by proving it. First for the integers, then for the rationals, then for the reals.

Comment: @Lubin Then for the complex numbers, then for the quaternions, then _not_ for the octonians…

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, right on. My position is that in mathematics, nothing is true. Until it’s proved.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Shouldn't you prove it for dual numbers before you move on to complex numbers?

Comment: @Matt I'm surprised you've heard of those, actually. (Once you've proven it for the reals, honestly, there's no reason to go in any order. You can immediately go to the octonians. It's just that the rationals are used to define the reals, so you should prove it for those before the reals. I only made the above comment because I wanted to mention octonians.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want an *intuitive* example, this might help you.

You currently have $x$ dollars (or whatever currency you prefer) in your wallet and you have to pay $x-1$ dollars, then what you have after the transaction is $x-(x-1)$. But since you pay *one less* than what you initially had, you certainly end up with $1$, i.e. $x-(x-1) = 1$.

We can apply similar reasoning to $x-x-1$. You start with $x$ dollars, then you pay $x$ dollars (you now have $0$ dollars), then you pay another $1$ dollar, and you end up in debt.

---

Now, what can you do completely algebraically? Since you maybe cannot always interpret the numbers to something like this. Well, whenever you have a minus in front of a parenthesis, like
$$-(x+y) $$ 
what you may do is that you can change the sign in front if you also change the sign of all terms within the parenthesis, i.e.

$$-(x+y) = (-x - y) = -x - y, $$

or in your example,

$$x-(x-1) = x+(-x+1) = x - x + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1. $$

The reason for this is well explained in the other answers :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer I found your example very helpful, if you could additionally explain the role of the parenthesis in this equation and how to deal with them this will be a superb answer.

Comment: You do the parentheses first. Current thinking has the order of operations as parentheses, exponents, multiplication, division, addition, then subtraction. So, putting numbers to it, you might start with 7-(7-1). Doing the parentheses first gives 7-6 = 1.

Comment: @Eff Is is acceptable to say that everything within parenthesis, for which no associativity applies, must be treated as a single number?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that we are in the filed of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ ( but in any field it's the same). In a field there are two operations $+$ ( the sum) and $\cdot$ ( the product) that have to satisfies some axioms ( see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html)), and a term $-x$ is defined as the element of the field such that $x+(-x)=0$ , called the opposed of $x$.

So when we write $x-(x-1)$ , using the axioms of a field, we interpret this as $x+[-(x-1)]$ where $-(x-1)$ is the opposite of $x-1$, i.e the element $a$ that, added to $x-1$ gives $0$: $a+(x-1)=0 $ but, from the definition of opposite and associativity of addition that means: $a+x+(-1)=0$ and we see that we must have $a=-x+1$.

Since we can prove that the opposite is unique, this gives the result : $ x-(x-1)=x+(-x)+1= 0+1=1$.

Comment: This is marked as arithmetic and precalc. Why would you even name fields?

Comment: I find this answer actually helpful, therefore I've added the tag "field-theory." Hope it doesn't bother you anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Subtraction is not associative, as you discovered.  Multiplication is.

http://www.mathwarehouse.com/dictionary/A-words/definition-of-associative-property.php

Comment: Links grow stale.

Answer (score 2):

The subtlety here is that addition that involves negative numbers is still commutative, whereas subtraction is not commutative.

So with $x + (-x) + 1$ we can shuffle the summands around all we want and result is the same: $-x$ zeroes out $x$ and we're left with 1. Thus $x + 1 + (-x) = 1 + (-x) + x = \ldots = 1$.

But with $x - (x - 1)$, a different result can be had just by shifting the parentheses: $(x - x) - 1 = -1$, as you already noticed. If someone just gave $x - x$ you would say that's 0. When that $x - x$ is put into the parentheses, it still evaluates to 0, regardless of what $x$ is to begin with.

By contrast, $x - 1$ evaluates to 0 only when $x = 1$. The expression $x - (x - 1)$ then consists of two numbers: $x$ and the number 1 less than $x$. The difference between these two numbers is 1, regardless of what $x$ is to begin with.

These distinctions are reflected in the terminology and grammar we use. When adding up two numbers, they're both summands. But when we subtract one number from another, the first number is the minuend and the second number is the subtrahend.

---

Similarly, multiplication that involves fractions is still commutative, but division is not.

Answer (score 1):

The negative number to a number $a$ is a number $b$ such that $a+b=0$. 
We denote that number $b$ as $-a$.

Now, the negative to $x-1$ is a $-x+1$, since 
$$(x-1)+(-x+1)=x-1+(-x)+1=0$$

Therefore $$x-(x-1)=x+(-x+1)=x+(-x)+1=1$$